# SSIS : Flat File - value displays as

Tags: ssis

I have an access DB. One column is of double-precision float format. Need to export these values to a Flat File.

Scenario 1:

MsAccess DB :  Column Value --> 12.34

FlatFile : Column Value --> 12.34

Scenario 2:

MsAccess DB :  Column Value --> 12

FlatFile : Column Value --> 12 instead want it to display as 12.00

Solution Tried:
1. Use Derived Column: added 0.001 now the value is 12.001, then using substring
substring(columnName,1,5), now the value is 12.00.

The problem is if the value is 120 or 1 then we will get 120.0 and 1.000.

Also, when I use export to flat file in MsAccess, the flat files shows the values as 12.00.

Is it possible to look for "."  and then skip the next two characters n delete the rest. If I convert the column to string type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, you can complete your code with FINDSTR() function

```
SUBSTRING(nb,1,FINDSTRING(nb,".",1) + 2)
```

We ask to cut your number (defined as a string) to the position of the first occurance of a point and add 2 position.

Is it your initial request?

Regards,
Arnaud